# Meteor 1.3 verify email when creating user

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

could someone please help me guiding me how to verify the email entered when a user is being created in meteor 1.3?

I am using this two packages: `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` `accounts-password` and the template provided by the first one `{{> loginButtons}}`.

My user is being created normally but I need to implement email verification. However, I am not sure how to proceed. What I have read [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendVerificationEmail) it is not clear for me. I do not know when and how to call that method.

Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I have read, I cannot implement email verification using the log in form provided by the mentioned packages. Instead, I have to implement my own one an call some methods to create users, verify email etc. This is a good example: https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/sign-up-with-email-verification/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement a server-side `onCreateUser` method, and call the `sendVerificationEmail` from there.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser